# What is Bud1% @ @ @ @E%DSDB` @ @ @?

Tags: php, osx-leopard, osx-server

I have made a small app for a client. The app scans a `files` directory which contains several text files. It then reads each file into a string. Every file has a title and the article  text. The two parts are separated with a pipe character like this: **`article_title|article_text`**. The script displays a list of links to open each article. The text of the link is the same as the article title.

Now, the client has apparently deleted an article, but is seeing an entry for the deleted file like the image bellow:
[image]

I searched for the string on the web and could actually find pages showing similar strings, e.g. [here](http://www.vta2d.info/bud1-edsdb/) which is apparently a deleted blog post.

What could be the cause for this? Is the file really deleted?

P.S.

1. The client has set the app on an intranet and cannot give me access, he sent me a screenshot.
2. I also don't know what his server OS is.
3. I'm not sure what to tag this question, maybe you can change the tags to better ones.

Comment: It could be some random Unix thing? What are you using to scan the directory? Does `glob()` give you the same thing?

Comment: Oh wow, this is an interesting one...

Comment: I'm using `$files = scandir('./files/');` and then use a `foreach` loop to read the file names. I have no access to the client's intranet to probe it further.

Comment: Hard to tell from a screenshot. But the `?@` looks like it might be UCS2/UTF16 intermingled with some ASCII strings. When a similar sequence appears on other websites, I would preclude a damaged filesystem. Might be just an application that writes to temporary files with corrupt filenames.

Comment: @mario - We actually have `content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"` header in the article lister and it does succeed in getting the characters right. But the `question-mark-diamonds (what are they called by the way?), suggest the system does not have the required charset to display them correctly. I might be wrong though.

Comment: The diamond question marks could just be NUL bytes `\0`. Setting the page output to UTF-8 won't convert the binary sequences into that. Could be anything. This will remain a riddle with just the screenshots.

Comment: Seems like a file actually has that content. Can all the files be checked to see that the content (or some equivalent garbage) is not in a file?

Comment: I have sent the client an altered script which uses `glob()` as suggested by alex. Waiting for him to provide more info. But even if the display problem is fixed by using `glob()`, we are just hiding some filesystem issue. Too bad I have no direct access.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OK, I found what it is. One of the Google search results pointed to [this](http://olimpic-club.ru/data/images/bg/.DS_Store) Which contains the following:

```
Bud1  ... @Ђ @Ђ @Ђ @E DSDB `Ђ @Ђ @Ђ @
```

Interestingly, the file is a `.DS_Store` [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store)! I checked a few .DS_Store files and they all contained the mysterious characters. These (hidden) files are generated automatically by Mac OS X. So the client should have accessed the folder from console and caused the creation of the hidden DS_Store (remember it's an intranet).

Comment: Yesterday, the client contacted me and verified that indeed this is what happened.

Comment: He probably opened the folder with Finder, it's Finder that creates these .DS_Store files.

Comment: I had the same issue and i resolved it by deleting all the .DS_Store files in my code files.

Answer (score 3):

For people that is still getting trouble with this in your application (after removing a file in my case), I solved it by removing recursively the .DS_Store files in the project folder.

On terminal, go to the project:

```
cd to/your/directory
```

And just type:

```
find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete
```

credits to Jon Bellah on his blog https://jonbellah.com/articles/recursively-remove-ds-store/

Answer (score 2):

This is information that the Finder (Mac equivalent of Windows Explorer) stores about files and folders. The best description of the format I found was here:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Mac::Finder::DSStore

The format is described as:

> The .DS_Store file holds a series of records giving attributes of the
>          files in the directory or of the directory itself (referred to as .).
>          These records are stored in a B-tree, and the pages of the B-tree are
>          stored in the file by a "buddy allocator" along with a small amount of
>          metadata. The allocator also provides a level of indirection, from
>          small integers to file offsets, presumably allowing blocks to be relocated as they grow and shrink.