# Bizarre HTML 'Bud1% @' Injection

Tags: html, expressionengine, code-injection

I'm developing a website locally in ExpressionEngine using MAMP Pro, and all of a sudden I'm getting the most bizarre issue.

My webfonts, served by Typekit, suddenly stopped functioning. Upon closer examination, I found that the second line of my Typekit embed code had been appended with `Bud1% @`. Here's my full Typekit code, for reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/*******.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}Bud1% @</script>
```

To clarify, this code is only injected when viewed in a browser, not in my code editor. I haven't yet tested whether or not it's being injected in the production environment.

Searching SO for a similar issue yields [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616918/what-is-bud1-edsdb), indicating that the issue is caused in some fashion by the Finder's hidden .DS_STORE files, but doesn't clarify how to rectify the problem.

I've tried removing the .DS_STORE file from the directory and recreating the affected HTML file, to no avail.

To further clarify, I'm developing on OSX Mountain Lion (10.8.2), using Sublime Text 2 as my code editor and Safari for testing. ExpressionEngine 2.5.5 is the CMS I'm using, and the whole thing resides in a Git repository managed by Git Tower.

Any ideas!? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I've solved my problem.**

This issue is specific to ExpressionEngine. It was due to a plugin I had installed called **SnippetsSync**.

The plugin had created an empty ExpressionEngine snippet from the `.DS_STORE` file in the directory, and was therefore replacing the `{ }` in my Typekit embed code with its contents, the dreaded `Bud1% @`.

If you're having the same issue, double-check that you don't have a blank snippet by going to *Design > Templates > Snippets*. If the issue persists, delete or disable the extension from *Add-Ons > Modules*.